# Python 2D Numpy Array to 1D (sort of..)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, transformation, encoder

Simple question, I want to get a 1D numpy array.

Given a 2D array where each row contains a single '1' value, how can it be converted to a 1D array, consisting of the column index of the '1' in the 2D array

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

to

```
[2 2 1 1 1 1 0]
```

How would I do it in python?
I don't know the terminology for it, do let me know the proper terms for such transformation.

Comment: Look for `numpy.argmax`.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the index with the maximum value along the first axis:

```
>>> a.argmax(axis=1)
array([2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

> `a.argmax(axis=None, out=None)`
>
> Return indices of the maximum values along the given axis.

If the other values are not necessarily less than one, filter for `1` first.
This gives an array of `True` and `False` values. Now, use `argmax()`:

```
>>> (a == 1).argmax(axis=1)
array([2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

`True` acts like a `1` and `False` like a `0`, because `bool` inherits from `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to get the hot index of a one hot encoded vector for each row.

This could be done as follows:

1. Multiply your matrix with a vector `[0 1 2]`, or more generic: `numpy.arange(matrix.shape[1])`
2. sum up your matrix rows: `numpy.sum(matrix, axis=1)`

numpy arrays also have the function `argmax`, which leads to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using numpy argmax as the following:

```
a=np.array([[ 0,  0,  1],[ 0,  0,  1], [ 0,  0,  1],[ 0,  1,  0],[ 0,  1,  0],[ 0,  1,  0],[ 1,0,0]])
a.argmax(1)
array([2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```